# Using functions in a underscore template

Tags: javascript, function, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to use a function in an Underscore template [as shown here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/26/view-helpers-for-underscore-templates/) but I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getProperty is not defined

Below is the code I am using

```
var CustomerDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "div",
    template: "#customer-detail-view-template",

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.initializeTemplate();
    },

    initializeTemplate: function() {
        this.template = _.template($(this.template).html());
    },

    render: function() {
        var data = this.model.toJSON();
        _.extend(data, viewHelper);
        console.log(data);
        var html = _.template($(this.template), data);
        $(this.el).html(html);
        return this;
    }
})
```

And the template:

```
 <script type="text/template" id="customer-detail-view-template">
    <div style="height: 70px;">
        <span class="displayText">
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">Full Name : <%= getProperty("full_name", null) %> </p>
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">Country Code : <%= getProperty("country_code", null) %></p>
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">street : <%= getProperty("street", null) %></p>
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">maiden_name : <%= getProperty("maiden_name", null) %></p>
        </span>
        <span class="displayTextRight">
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">marital_status_code : <%= getProperty("marital_status_code", null) %></p>
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">tax_id_number : <%= getProperty("tax_id_number", null) %></p>
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">primary_phone : <%= getProperty("primary_phone", null) %></p>
            <p class="searchResultsAuxInfo">customer_number : <%= getProperty("customer_number", null) %></p>
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
```

The view helper object looks like this:

```
var viewHelper = {
    getProperty:function(propertyName, object) {
        if(typeof(object) === "undefined"){
            object = this["attributes"];
        }
        for (i in object) {
            if (_.isObject(object[i])) {
                var currentObj = object[i];
                if(_.has(currentObj, propertyName)){
                    return currentObj[propertyName];
                }
                this.getProperty(propertyName, currentObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for the `viewHelper` object and show us exactly what `data` looks like right before you call `_.template`.

Comment: Hi i have added the code to the above question please check

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is that once you're inside `render`, `this.template`:

```
var html = _.template($(this.template), data);
```

is already a compiled template function:

```
initializeTemplate: function() {
    this.template = _.template($(this.template).html());
}
```

The [`_.template`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) call:

> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.

So you're saying this:

```
_.template($(some_compiled_template_function).html(), data);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is executing the [`$(function() { ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) form of `$()` and that:

> Binds a function to be executed when the DOM has finished loading.

That little bit of confusion makes everything go haywire and chaos abounds. Fix how you use the template and things will start making more sense:

```
render: function() {
    //...
    var html = this.template(data);
    //...
}
```

Your `this.template` will be a function inside `render` so call it as a function.

Demo (with some simplifications for clarity): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SgEzH/

Answer (score 0):

according to the blog article you refer to,

just delete this line will make it work: "this.initializeTemplate();"